# How to send input hidden in React JS?

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I have this form, and I would like to send these values. I know we have to use `setState()` to store data but how does it work for `input type="hidden"`?

1. First question: How to store input hidden to setState ?
2. Second question: How to serialize data like form.serialize() ?
3. Third question: How to send these serialize values? Ajax or Axios, who is the better?

Here is the code:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

   /**
    $.ajax({
        url: "post.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: DATA,
        success:function(data) {

        }
    });
    **/
 }

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
                        <input type="email" name="email_user" placeholder="Email" />
                        <input type="password" name="password_user" placeholder="Mot de passe" />
                        <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is complex for all your questions.

First of all, it depends on the task: if you just want to send asynchonous request to server on form submit, you don't need to use `Component` state. Here is a link to the relevant section of the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). And use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to access inputs data.

```
class FormComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Send your ajax query via jQuery or Axios (I prefer Axios)
        axios.get('your_url', {
            params: {
              action: this.actionInput.value,
              email: this.emailInput.value,
              password: this.passwordInput.value,
            }
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" 
                       ref={(input) => { this.actionInput = input }} />

                <input type="email" name="email_user" placeholder="Email" 
                       ref={(input) => { this.emailInput = input }}/>

                <input type="password" name="password_user" placeholder="Mot de passe" 
                       ref={(input) => { this.passwordInput = input }}/>

                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to send asynchonous request for each input. I want to send all inputs together at the same time by "onSubmit". That's why I want to serialize them and sends it in Ajax

Comment: @Steffi then check the documentation for axios/fetch or whatever you are using... odds are you're going to submit either JSON or a form-post encoded payload.

Comment: @Steffi, you, of course, can access all inputs with refs. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @ShabashP Thanks Shabash! So with these "ref" we don't handleChange onChange anymore? We don't store data un state. That's right?

Comment: @Steffi, yes. The main idea is to not use `state` when you can do without it. Within the current task it is. And here is another usefull link to [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).

Answer (score 3):

All data can be stored on React's state, but if you still need to have inputs on your form you can do something like this:

```js
const handleSubmit = e => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const inputs = Object.values(e.target)
        .filter(c => typeof c.tagName === 'string' && c.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input')
        .reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.name]: curr.value }), {});

     setFormVals({ ...formVals, ...inputs });
}
```

See the demo below:

```js
const Demo = () => {
    const [formValues] = React.useState({});

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const inputs = Object.values(e.target)
            .filter(c => typeof c.tagName === 'string' && c.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input')
            .reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.name]: curr.value }), {});

        console.log(inputs);
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input name="name" placeholder="Name" value={formValues.name} />
            <input name="email" placeholder="Email" value={formValues.email} />
            <input name="hiddenInput" value="hiddenValue" type="hidden" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

If you know what the inputs that you need you can do something like this:

```js
const Demo = () => {
    const formRef = React.useRef(null);
    const [formValues, setFormValues] = React.useState({});
    
    const handleChange = e => {
      setFormValues({
        ...formValues,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    }
    
    const handleSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setFormValues({ ...formValues, hiddenInput: formRef.current.hiddenInput.value });
    }
    
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRef}>
            <input name="name" placeholder="Name" value={formValues.name} onChange={handleChange} />
            <input name="email" placeholder="Email" value={formValues.email} onChange={handleChange} />
            <input name="hiddenInput" value="hiddenValue" type="hidden" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(formValues, null, 2)}</pre>
        </form>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:

1. Since you know how to use component's state you may set the value as : `<input type='text' value={this.state.foo} />` or even via props passing `<input type='hidden' value={this.props.foo} />`
2. You don't need to serialise anything at all. Use your component's local state or even a state container like Redux or Flux in order to pick the appropriate data. Take a look at this fairly simple example:

   ```
   var SuperForm = React.createClass({
   getInitialState() {
     return { 
       name: 'foo', 
       email: 'baz@example.com'
     };
   },

   submit(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log("send via AJAX", this.state)
   },

   change(e,key){
     const newState = {};
     newState[key] = e.currentTarget.value;
     this.setState(newState)
   },

   render: function() {
       return (
       <div>
         <label>Name</label>
         <input 
           onChange={(e) => this.change(e,'name')}
           type="text" 
           value={this.state.name} />
         <label>Email</label>  
         <input 
           onChange={(e) => this.change(e,'email')}
           type="text" 
           value={this.state.email} />
         <button onClick={this.submit}>Submit</button>
       </div>
     );
   }});
   ```

   [Demo](http://jsbin.com/bagalajequ/edit?js,console,output)
3. AJAX is a set of web development techniques while Axios is a JavaScript framework. You may use jQuery, Axios or even vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks man. Looks good. But how about the `input type=hidden` please?

Comment: @Steffi Same as `<input type='text'`> I have made a small typo in my first answer. Still if you are planning to post the form via AJAX you don't need to inject any hidden form elements. Pass your data to your state.